# Set center point for svg group with javascript

Tags: javascript, svg, position, two.js

In a game I am currently making you are in a map which is build from nodes and you are warping to different nodes when you click on them. My current map looks like that (created with two.js it's a svg group where each circle and line is svg path element, ex:

```
<path transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 553 120)" d="M 8 0 C 8 2.02 7.085 4.228 5.656 5.656 C 4.228 7.085 2.02 8 0 8 C -2.021 8 -4.229 7.085 -5.657 5.656 C -7.086 4.228 -8 2.02 -8 0 C -8 -2.021 -7.086 -4.229 -5.657 -5.657 C -4.229 -7.086 -2.021 -8 -0.001 -8 C 2.02 -8 4.228 -7.086 5.656 -5.657 C 7.085 -4.229 8 -2.021 8 0 Z " fill="#003251" stroke="#ebebeb" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="1" fill-opacity="1" visibility="visible" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="4" id="19"></path>
```

And the map looks like that:
[image: game map]

The marked in red node is indicator for your current position on the zone/map. How can I re-position the svg group so the current player position to be always in the center of the container shifting the whole map to left/right/top/bottom and become like that:
[image]
[image]

Using the following function I am able to change x,y coordinates of the svg group:

```
function shiftMap(id_attr, offsetX, offsetY) {
    let elem = $(id_attr);
    if (elem) {
        let params = ' translate(' + offsetX + ',' + offsetY + ')';
        elem.attr('transform', params);
    }
}
```

I also have a function to detect current player position node coordinates, so I tried to do:

```
//where playerPosX = X of the current player node location (red mark)
//and playerPosY = Y of the current player node location (red mark)
shiftMap("svgMapID", playerPosX, playerPosY);
```

Unfortunately the position is not accurate and map shifts/moves everywhere, goes out of the container bounds, etc. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Hint: It may be possible to do via twojs anchor point, but I am not sure how. More info here: https://two.js.org/#two-anchor

Answer (score 1):

You have to calculate bounding box of your svg-group and move the group, considering outer offsets of the group itself and inner offsets relative to your center node.

[image]

Let's say you want this new random node to be at center of your group, highlighted in red.

Then you calculate its `X` and `Y` related to the container. Let's say that `X = 400`, `Y = 200`.

Then you calculate the bounding box of all your map group related to the container.

In this example, `Y1` is probably going to be `0`, where `X1` you have to find. Try using `group.getBoundingClientRect(shallow)`, as described in [Two.js docs](https://two.js.org/#two-group). Let's say that 'X1 = 300', 'Y1 = 0'.

Having your container W(width) = 1000 and H(height) = 700, let's calculate your final coordinates:

**`finalX`**`= (W/2) - (X + X1) = 500 - 700 =`**`-200`**

**`finalY`**`= (H/2) - (Y + Y1) = 350 - 200 =`**`150`**

That means that you have to move your map group `-200` by `X` (200 to the left) and `150` by `Y` (150 to the bottom)